# How to modify properties of kendo charts using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, kendo-ui

I have an asp.net application in which I am using Kendo UI charts. I have almost 10 bullet charts in my aspx page. If I want to change the width of all bullet charts, I have to do it manually one by one. I want a javascript function which has some parameters related to the kendo bullet charts that I can modify there and redraw the chart with modified parameters.

Let me know how can I achieve this. Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

HTML -

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
   <div id="chart" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(window).on("resize", function() {
          $(".chart-wrapper").attr("width","100"); // replace 100 with required width here
          kendo.resize($(".chart-wrapper"));
        });
</script>
```

SOURCE - `http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-in-responsive-web-pages`

LINK To responsive CSS - `http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bullet-charts/index`